# How to Combine multiple files in BizTalk?

Tags: biztalk

I have multiple flatfiles (CSV) (with multiple records) where files will be received randomly. I have to combine them (records) with unique ID fields.

**How can I combine them, if there is no common unique field for all files, and I don't know which one will be received first?**

Here are some files examples:
[image]

In real there are 16 files. 
Fields and records are much more then in this example.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that at least one file contains the correlation? Will the files be coming in within a certain timeframe?

Comment: There is no one file containing correlation .We have chain of files and chain of correlations . Files come within 1-15 minutes (we use parallel convoy to obtain them) . We are trying to join files using "map" but can't find the way to do that according to the logic (chain to each other by unique fields and get one file in  output ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid trying to do this purely in XSLT/BizTalk orchestrations/C# code.  These are fairly simple flat files.  Load them into SQL, and create a view to join your data up.

You can still use BizTalk to pickup/load the files.  You can also still use BizTalk to execute the view or procedure that joins the data up and sends your final message.

There are a few questions that might help guide how this would work here:

1. When do you want to join the data together? What triggers that (a time of day, a certain number of messages received, a certain type of message, a particular record, etc)?  How will BizTalk know when it's received enough/the right data to join?
2. What does a canonical version of this data look like?  Does all of the data from all of these files truly get correlated into one entity (e.g. a "Trade" or a "Transfer" etc.)?

I'd probably start with defining my canonical entity, and then look towards the path of getting a "complete" picture of that canonical entity by using SQL for this kind of case.

Comment: This is the answer I was going to propose as well. +1

Comment: Thank you for your response . 
1. Data have to be joined right after last 16th file is gotten . Each file has it's own schema and now we are using "Parallel convoy" to wait for all.
2. Yes all the data correlated into one entity (but we have chain type correlation)

At this precise moment in time we want to come up is the biztalk appropriate tool to solve this kind of task or writing our own solution would be better.That's why we don't want to use SQL procedures or view's which obviously can simply solve the problem

Comment: You could do this in XSLT or using C#, but it'll require custom XSLT (the BizTalk mapper doesn't offer very support for grouping/joining data) or custom C# code.  SQL would be much easier to maintain and make sense of.