# BizTalk Map and Table Looping functoid

Tags: mapping, biztalk

Mapping picture with output XML: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Pr63.jpg)

[image]

In this example I have multiple files, where I want to combine 2 different fields together  in each iteration. Holding and Portfolio **Max Occurs** is **Unbounded**.
In each iteration from PortfolioID filed Table Looping functoid takes values from each row (AU19014,AU19016,AU19015), but from AccountID takes only first row value(AU106) and repeat it in each iteration.

**Why it can't loop in AccountID field too? And how with mapping I can do this, To get all values from differant files in each iteration?**

Comment: Rather than giving us only a picture, could you give us simplified schemas and inputs XML file so we can replicate the issue?  However usually if it becomes too hard to do in the map, the answer is to do it in custom xslt that the map calls.

Comment: By this link you can find file examples.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43753045/how-to-combine-multiple-files-in-biztalk?noredirect=1#comment74548257_43753045 But it will be grate if you help with that question too, there was an answer, but I have to do it only with BizTalk (without SQL as they say). And I don't know XSLT to write code on it, that's why I try to combine them with MAP.

Comment: I suggest to use Inline XSLT handling these kind iterations